# Embedded soundcloud audio does not work with sandbox in iframes in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, embed, soundcloud, flash

**Problem:**
I have a html file which calls another html file through an iframe with sandbox. The inner file contains iframe given by soundcloud to embed. Now this soundcloud widget does not work.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <iframe width= "100%" height="450" src= "inneriframe.html" sandbox></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>`

And the inneriframe.html contains iframe I got from soundcloud.com inneriframe.html is:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/36700916&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" ></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>`

**Observations:**

```
 1. It works for some files and does not work for others.
 2. It works on firefox and not on chrome.
 3. If we disable flash player from chrome plugins, it works.
```

**Possible reasons:**
Perhaps for some files soundcloud first check if flash player is available, run it through flash player else through HTML5. In such cases it finds that flash player is available and hence tries through it but sandbox restricts flash player and hence it does not work.

For other files perhaps soundcloud directly runs through HTML5. Also since chrome implements sandbox most strictly, hence it is a problem in chrome only.

Working embedding:

`<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/211417319&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>`

Non-working embedding:

`<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/216846955&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>`

Kindly help me in:

```
1. resolving issue, if there is some way.
2. to differentiate files which works and which does not work and why?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the Chrome/Flash issue, I think what may be happening is you may have some conflicting Flash updates in Chrome. Chrome by default has Flash integrated and each update to Chrome also adds the most recent version of Flash. If you've installed Flash separately, it could also be installed for Chrome, so the two versions might be in conflict with each other. You need to  disable one/ the second instance of Flash - that's why disabling the plugin in Chrome works.  I would recommend however, that you ensure that your version of Chrome is up to date and/or that you update your flash plugin by doing the following:

In the address bar [of Chrome] type chrome://components, then under "pepper_flash," click 'Check for update'. That may work. So it is not a general issue, it will vary from machine to machine. A pain, i know.

Regarding the some-play some-don't issue, this is a known FF-soundcloud issue. Apparently if you enter Firefox 'Safe mode' all the tracks will play. (you can enter Safe mode by clicking the menu icon, then help and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled then select Start in Safe Mode (don't Refresh Firefox) ).

Hope this helps!

Rachel

Comment: Thanks for help! But firstly, I have verified that no extra flash player is installed on my chrome, its only the which is default in chrome. Secondly, it also works well if we remove the sandbox. Hence perhaps sandbox is restricting flash from being played.

Comment: you may have flash installed on ie, or on our pc, stand-alone. that could be it too